# Are 'aircraft identification' questions using photos eligible for duplicate voting?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, vote-to-close

Not post-specific, rather general policy, but I will use two posts as an example:

A recent question asked: [What is this aircraft that has flown over my house all day?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/60769/14897)

To which I voted duplicate for: [Is this a C-17 (and why is it here)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57406/14897) And the asker agreed hence the "Community ♦" vote.

I voted based on both posts (photos) having similar angles to the same plane (a C-17).

But a comment said:

> I disagree that this question is a duplicate. One cannot search based on just an image on SE, you can only search text. Given that a person asking to identify an aircraft inherently does not know the name of the aircraft, how can they be expected to find a previous post asking about a C-17?

To which I replied:

> And that is why humans are involved, and not a search robot (note that OP agreed it solved their question). The other extreme is having 10 distinct questions for the same aircraft-identification, say a 747 – does not make it right.

So far there are two views, please discuss and vote below (using answers please, so they can be voted both ways).

---

From personal experience, although I'm not sure if policy driven, duplicate voting based on photos alone is allowed on EarthScience.SE. And I'd imagine the same for species-identification on Biology.SE. (This comment is to highlight that it would not affect only Aviation.SE, so perhaps we can draw from wider-site consensus.)

Comment: Thanks, I was also considering posting on Meta about what to do with these posts :)

Answer (score 3):

Drawing from similar tags *here,* **feature**-identification questions are closed as duplicate (asker also not knowing the feature's name; [15 occurrences](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-identification%5D+duplicate%3A1)).*

I don't think aircraft-identification should be any different.

---

<s>* I'm guessing more than 15 (mods can help) because abandoned-closed are automatically deleted (?).</s>

Comment: duplicates are never automatically deleted.

Answer (score -1):

One option: Given the constraints of the site, and the desire not to have a constant stream of "what is this plane" posts, we should prohibit such posts.

I can't think of a way to make it easy for a user to search all of the posts and compare their photo, given the non-photo oriented nature of SE. We don't have any sort of way to view photos from multiple posts all at once, as far as I am aware. Therefore it would be overly burdensome to expect each person to check every previous "aircraft-identification" post before posting themselves. If it is too burdensome to search previous posts, and we allow "aircraft-identification" posts, then we may start clogging up the front page with requests.

---

I definitely don't like the idea of banning the posts, but I feel that flagging it as a duplicate, while accurate, may be discouraging to new users. Obviously banning the posts is even more discouraging to those users, though, so I'm conflicted on the best course. But I felt I should at least present this option.

Answer (score -1):

A danger here is what happens when there is a disagreement on what the aircraft is.

The vote as duplicate system could be used to prevent others posting different opinions, bypassing the normal up/down vote system.

If it is very obvious and the OP agrees I think it would be safe to close as duplicate, though if there’s any doubt or dispute it should stay open.

Comment: IMO for that worst case scenario, the same reopen mechanism would apply. An edit to be made to clarify how the supposed duplicate isn't.